# Set powershell variable in ps1 script by a paramater

Tags: powershell, scripting, ps1

How to set Powershell variable into ps1 script before the execution of the script

example:

application execution path:
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:/script.ps1"

paramater:
$WhichSite= "StackOverflow"

ps1 contains:
curl -UseBasicParsing "http://www.$WhichSite.com"

I tried the example above to set the $WhichSite = "stackoverflow"

But it did not work

result expected of executing powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:/script.ps1":
curl -UseBasicParsing "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the best thing would be to pass a parameter to the script and then call the curl function from within. You might consider something like this inside of script.ps1:

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.String]
        $WhichSite
    )
    
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing "Http://$WhichSite.com"
```

Then, to run the script from a PowerShell window, you can do:

`./script.ps1 -WhichSite "stackoverflow"`

You can set the execution policy for PowerShell for the current session by running:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process`

So that you don't have to add it in front of your script execution everytime time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the execution policy tip, Will it work also for numeric value and should I execute all together or separate the app execution path than the parameter C:\script.ps1 -WhichSite "stackoverflow" or app exec path: C:\script.ps1 parameter: -WhichSite "stackoverflow" cause I tried both did not work maybe cause the the value is number that's why it did not work

Comment: Apologies, I mistyped the execution string - if you change directory to be in the C:\ directory, the execution is `./script.ps1 -WhichSite "stackoverflow"`

It should be executed as I just typed it. Numbers should work as well, they'll just be converted to strings, not integers.

Comment: On second thought, you are probably better off using `Invoke-WebRequest`, I've updated my answer to reflect that. Eliminates potential `PATH` issues with curl.exe

Comment: Thanks for the help I tried it but still did not work, note that the parameter is numeric. the Invoke-WebRequest will not work since Internet explorer is disabled by GPO.

Comment: If you pass the parameter in quotes, such as "123", then it will be interpreted as a string. Invoke-WebRequest does not have a dependency on IE, I'm running the above snippet on a machine without IE installed it is appropriately returning the request data. How are you executing this script?

Comment: Through an application called communicator by Bicom here is how I execute it in these images https://pasteboard.co/g7hj72bZnRqV.png https://pasteboard.co/TPNtA224N4CR.png https://pasteboard.co/DR6MD47WHdxw.png I tried both combined/separated exec path and parameter